# Will my AngularJS 1.x app still work after Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm near production with my project where i used `AngularJS` 1.6 and i always ignored `Angular2`.

I don't plan on refactoring my app to Angular 2, we are already far away and i just want to hand over the app to the client and move on.

My question is will the application continue to work for the next 3 to 5 years ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You have the assets, everything is working now. It may be hard to maintain or upgrade, sure.

Comment: of course it would. i think angular 1 has long time before they make stop development or maintenance or support.

Comment: You shouldn't need to upgrade/refactor it to Angular 2 just yet. It is hard to believe that for the next 3 to 5 years your app won't need any updating or upgrading, adding new features and so forth. Keep in mind that Angular 2 has adopted the component based architecture, if you're building you're app this way, it should be a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work until something non-backwards compatible wont be introduced to new browsers which will brake the `Angular 1.x` framework and stop it from running on it.

How probable is it in the next 3 to 5 years? Not probable at all. Backwards compatibility is one of the top-most priorities, nobody wants to publish a browser which will "brake" a website.

Other question is the maintenance and support of `Angular 1.x`, that is, will be there a fix if some bug will be found in the framework?

In my opinion 3 to 5 years is a really sure bet, the code base around written using AngularJS 1.x is so huge, and the effort needed to migrate it to Angular 2 is so big, that the support will for sure continue in that time frame.

But beyond that? Well, better slowly start preparing a migration, because in 3-5 years, your software will begin to be considered as "legacy software", and nobody wants that etiquette ;)